# Add html data attribute to Joomla 3.4.8 module

Tags: html, joomla

I'm trying to add `data-uk-sticky` attribute to a Joomla module that displays a sidebar menu (to make it sticky).

For that, I created an alternative layout by copying

`/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php`

To:

`/modules/mod_menu/tmpl/sticky.php`

In the sticky.php file I wrapped the whole content in a div like:

```
<div data-uk-sticky><ul class="nav menu<?php echo $class_sfx;?>"<?php
```

In the module admin, I can now select `Sticky` in the `Alternative Layout` configuration.

However, when reloading the page I can't find the div I created. Why not?

I also tried copying the whole `mod_menu` to the `template/html` folder but the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<div data-uk-sticky>` isn't a proper tag. You need to either ID it or class it, but I would suggest IDing it.

```
<div id="data-uk-sticky">
```

Then when you're editing in a bootstrap.css or a custom.css:

```
#data-uk-sticky {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
width:/*define your width*/;
/*Any other stylings you wish to apply*/
}
```

Your problem was that your `<div>` tag was not in proper syntax. Also ensure that you close it at the end of your module file.

Cheers.